How to Advance Deep Sea Technology using Metallic, Oxygenating, Geobattery "Flowers"
So it turns out there DO be oxygen in the deep after all!
(Source)

"...small metallic nodules found in the north Pacific's Clarion-Clipperton Zone (CCZ) produce oxygen through seawater electrolysis, where seawater splits into oxygen and hydrogen in the presence of an electric charge."


"So-called polymetallic nodules are common on the ocean's abyssal plains, which are flat regions of the seafloor between 10,000 and 20,000 feet (3,000 to 6,000 m) below the ocean surface. These nodules mostly contain oxides of iron and manganese, but they also hold metals like cobalt, nickel and lithium, as well as rare earth elements such as cerium that are essential components of electronics and low-carbon technologies."

My Idea
I'm having my deep-dwelling race, that I've mentioned (before), take advantage of this incredible miracle by gathering and studying the nodules, in order to hopefully recreate them and help spread oxygen on a bigger scale.
Assume their current level of technology is earlier on the tech tree than the aforementioned post. Not sure what time period would be appropriate. Due to their lack of smelting, I'll go and say probably around the Neolithic Revolution Age? The discovery of geobatteries would seem to be their equivalent of fire but discovered comparatively later than ours. They are familiar with more advanced technology from land dwellers (who we'll say are in the 1400s Medieval stage equivalent just so we can have a point of reference) and the deep dwellers have even scavenged remnants from whatever washes or sinks into the sea. But being deep dwellers, they can't stay in the upper zones for too long. Especially in the daylight hours, which limits them to either dusk/dawn or night. So if there was to be any trade with others, it would probably be rather limited and tenuous at best. Not to mention any uses of above world technology would be limited for the lower depths.
As far as "mining" goes, I'm following the advice of others on this site (like here) by having them grinding, raking, and other repetitive motions for retrieving any deeper metals that aren't as easily accessible.
Using these metals, I want my people to be able to create the equivalent of plants from the land by making more geobatteries that use electrolysis to split water into hydrogen and oxygen. Possibly shaping them into floral shapes.
My hope is that I would like to put this on a large scale with the following characteristics:

Large fields of these metallic "flowers" that can provide an oasis where needed (like public gardens, private yards, etc)
Bigger "flowers" that (ideally) provide more oxygen
Can be "planted" in or near future workshops to provide oxygen for things like smithing, building technology, burning things underwater, etc
Improve standard of living for deeper folk, possibly aiding their metabolism and allowing more advancements
Make the deeper zones more productive, even if slightly
Possibility of leading to more advanced technological achievements like factories

What am I handwaving?

I'm going to ignore the evolution of such a race and why they'd be in the deep to begin with for brevity's sake.
Also for brevity's sake I'm going to assume that there'd be enough metals on the seabed to feasibly do this.
Also temporarily ignoring why they don't find better ways to trade instead.

My Question!
Can these geobatteries be able to oxygenate the deep sea enough to help the deep dwellers advance technologically?
Relevant questions that don't exactly answer my problem:
They both touch on electrolysis but this was before the geobatteries were discovered and made public knowledge.

Could you develop Electrolysis with Pre-Modern technology?

Electrolysis Assisted Aerobic Organisms


If there's anything else anyone needs to know, please feel free to ask!
Edit:
I altered my question in hopes of being more focused, and added more info.
The deep dwellers are capable of:

forming water tight containers for different reasons involving things from land
studying the physics of pressure
studying methods of preservation
having access to brine pools and salts
withstanding the heat of hydrothermal vents for a time

They lived in the mid zones of the ocean, traveling across them for various needs, before advancing enough (with the aid of discovering the geobatteries) where they were able to establish some settlements in the deeper zones. One of the reasons why they were so focused on advancement was to free themselves from relying on the land dwellers and wanting to get away from them.
(Debating on how this should work)
They breathe oxygen and can store it in their bodies like cetaceans and even slow down their metabolism. However, they have gills like nudibranchs on their backs/sides which they can retract within themselves for protection or not in immediate use. In oxygen-poor zones or if they’re running low, they can create “emergency” oxygen by using electrolysis in nudibranch-styled gills. However, this is of course costly so it’s used sparingly.

Not very clear where the energy would be coming from to power the electrolysis. Big difference in some thing that runs at mm of node per 100k years  and mm per day.(rough equivalent energy of the electrolysis flowers).

@GaultDrakkor Are you referring to the nodules or the deep dwellers’ biology? If the latter, I assume they store the energy from the food they eat as they are capable of slowing down their metabolism. But like I said this is a rare occurrence and only in emergencies.

I am referring both the metal nodes being very low energy intensity, and the people needing much higher energy intensity. Such that the geobatteries /flowers with a million fold the energy intensity of the metal nodes, need a source of energy. What is that source of energy for the geobatteries to operate?

@GaultDrakkor According to the article: “ This charge may come from the difference in electric potential that exists between metal ions within the nodules, which leads to a redistribution of electrons, according to the study.”

The metallic nodes are converting at something like 1 Mol per decade and your mer people need a rate closer 1 Mol per hour. it requires a source of energy to boost the rate.

Plausibility Checks
Geobattery / Electrolysis / Oxygen generation

I think with those "nodules" you refer to the Manganese Deposits found in the deepsea.

I could not find evidence on how much Oxygen is really produced by one nodule. I only found repeatedly "Oxygen levels rose". It is implied that the amount of Oxygen probably influenced the forming of our atmosphere. But the timescale is not mentioned. Does it need billions of years to form a meaningful amount of Oxygen by those processes (happening at 1.5V, no clue if it can be increased by doubling that voltage or something in that lane).

Oxygen saturation of water: I think, your idea is to "add more oxygen to the seawater". But this is not going to work. Water is only capable of holding a finite amount of Oxygen. Depending on factors like depth/pressure, salinity, temperature. Any Oxygen that water cannot hold will be "gased out". Meaning it will form small bubbles and rise to the surface. From there it dissipates into the atmosphere. Over the course of billions of years "The Great Oxidation Event" on earth (and it is considered mainly caused by Cyanobacteria that produce Oxygen as a byproduct) the excess Oxygen became so much, that it formed the atmosphere in our today's condition (further processes for Nitrogen etc. not considered here).
--> This means, you can assume that our oceans are totally saturated with Oxygen (as physically possible; there are low-saturated zones also). If you add processes to produce more Oxygen underwater, this will be a very slow and localized effect and only rise upwards (gas is lighter than water). Oxygen will not spread in the ocean (because it is saturated already).


Mining

Those nodules are also called "Polymetallic" because they are a good mixture of traces of different metals. Primarily Iron, Nickel, Cobalt, Copper and Manganese of course. Along with precious metals, like gold, silver, and Rare Earth metals in ever diminishing amounts. All those metals are tightly bound together and are oxidized, meaning they are not pure, but have all formed reactions with Oxygen.

The nodules are very interesting for us (our modern demands on technology) because those nodules contain everything we need to make batteries and high-tech stuff like computer equipment of all sorts, CPUs, hard drives, SSDs, memory chips, electro-motors, coils, condensators, capacitators, ferro-magnets, LEDs, nano-technology, etc. etc. - And we are short on mining sites above sea-level to satisfy ever growing demands (also: political reasons because those metals are "rare" and localized on certain spots).

You said your merfolk is at the level of neolithic time. Their demands would be highly focused on Iron and Copper in great abundance, Nickel maybe also to form alloys. Ferro-magnetic properties of Nickel, Cobalt and Copper might be interesting to individuals (scientists), but all others probably value those only as juwelery. All Rare Earth Metals are totally useless to them until they have need for semi-conductors and computer technology.

Smelting of "Polymetallic Manganese Nodules" needs a great deal of knowledge and a highly sophisticated smelting process to separate all the metals without losing to much of it. Also Re-Oxidizing the metals is something special.
They might be able to "brute force" smelting only the main metals and knowingly or unknowingly discard the others (they will form the clinker/waste even more munched together and harder to separate).

Needs: If your merfolk is in need of the primary metals (iron, copper, nickel), then there is either "better ore" available somewhere with much higher yields of those metals or they are in need of trade with the landfolks.


Trading

Since the landfolk is more advanced, maybe their demands are different and they are more after to precious metals, even if they are in smaller traces, but being "gifted" to them by the merfolk as trading items or even as kind of "currency", makes it easier to smelt those brute-force for gold and silver only, than trying to find and mine gold and silver themselves somewhere far away and hard to reach. Maybe this "Manganese Ore Trading" becomes a thing between the two folks. Merfolk providing the ore, landfolk providing the smelting and smithing.

The merfolk surely has two mega advantages: (A) They have the resources and (B) they can reach and harvest them fairly easily even (because, underwater breathing and intelligent enough to use tools, and the potatos just lying around, not being held in stone etc.). That gives them a de-facto monopoly which they can utilize to trade with the landfolk for all kinds of stuff.


Technological Advancements

As I understand it, the merfolk has grills or some natural ability to "breathe water". Do they really depend on Oxygen? Or is more Oxygen and less water even deadly for them (like for a fish on land). The question is: Would they really want a higher "oxygen atmosphere" in their underwater sea cities?

The second thing is, the technological stuff. Like being able to smelt, weld, explode, light etc. underwater. (There are ways to achieve this underwater also, like plasma welding, Thermite or phosphorous reactions).
I think to be used like at the surface, you need kind of a evacuated base, a sealed house or dome in which the Oxygen atmosphere can dominate and the amount of water can be reduced or removed entirely. This would come down to them as if we would be underwater or in space. Meaning, they can only operate there with special breathing equipment.


Conclusion:
I don't think the pure presence of those nodules can advance you merfolk in a revolutionized way. To make the best use of it, they need to advance their base tech-level first. They do have advantages when it comes to trading with the land people. Increasing the oxygen levels underwater without further technological explanations (underwater domes etc.) is not possible (or only in restricted amounts) and the health impact on merfolk needs to be addressed.

(sigh) That’s what I feared. :( I figured they’d notice the water being “fresher” over the nodules and put two and two together there. I didn’t know if it would help to mention this, or if I should keep it, but this people may be able to perform bursts of their own electrolysis within nudibranch-like gills on their sides, to make emergency bursts of oxygen from time. They draw in water, shock it, and either release or keep the hydrogen. Thought they could make connections between themselves and the nodules. Is there a way to “fan” or spread the oxygen out like a fish tank oxygenator instead?

Furthermore, I also knew it wouldn't do anything massive like affect the ENTIRE deep; but if we could have those "oases" I talked about, then that might still do a world of good. Perhaps the few times they interact with the upper levels or land dwellers, they could pick up on stuff or experiment?

I also wanted them to become “independent” from the land dwellers as part of their timeline hence why they would want to discover welding, smithing, maybe even electroplating (like the Moche) etc on their own. They actually DO, probably earlier on their tech tree, learn how to make sealed off containers but for different reasons. I was trying to avoid unnecessary info, but seems I might need to update my post after all.

If you think their biology is able to handle the oxygen, one plausible way would be using those nodules to "pave" the ground of their cities, maybe use them as building blocks for houses (at least for an outside shell) etc. This way, the oxygen would rise up more or less "constantly". It is also always a way to handwave those things or better: find a story to cover the "implausibilities". If you want those plants, why not. For the plot this is surely fine. I don't want to discourage your story, just give you hints on points to think about. You have the power over all plot solutions!

Also: If they can fashion smaller containers, this would surely help as well. Think about those laboratory glass boxes with two rubber gloves mounted to it. Inside there can be all sorts of atmospheric conditions. Maybe they just have many of those (with air ventilation system) to do their welding, soldering etc. inside of such localized "domes".

The ocean is absolutely not saturated! The surface layers may be close to saturation, but colder water holds more oxygen than hot water, so wherever you have water cooling off, not in contact with the surface, it will be unsaturated. And wherever you have animals consuming oxygen in the depths, it will not stay saturated. This is part of why global warming is dangerous--by warming the poles, we reduce the rate of downwelling that introduces cold, oxygen-rich water to the depths, turning them anoxic.

@LoganR.Kearsley: Maybe I use the term "saturation" wrong. I mean it as: The ocean is at max oxygen amount, because there is no more oxygen produced anywhere (the nodules, cyanobacteria, plants, wind mixing, etc. all are doing their thing already). If the nodules were made more potent then the extra oxygen would rise to the top (because gas), not stay or spread in the water. Would you agree? Or do you mean, the oxygen would stay in the water (at that depth?), because it is able to hold it?

@Antares Oh no! I know you mean no harm! And I actually did have that exact idea of a dome with gloves where they could smith/weld/invent/etc. Science can only do so much in fiction but damn if it doesn’t inspire a lot. Maybe I could create some structures like some kind of domes or awnings that could hold the oxygen where people and animals could go under. At least temporarily. I didn’t even think of the oxygen just floating away in a straight line. I thought there could be like a continuous flow and spread out.

@Antares Perhaps some structures or pipes could be installed to direct them to important places like smithies or shops.

@Thunderhammer: Sure, they can collect those nodules in tanks to "harvest" the oxygen and pipe them to certain factories/smiths/etc. The amount of oxygen that can be produced is open to debate, but there surely are explanations possible.
Also I wanted to add, I like your idea with the emergency-electrolysis-gills. This makes it plausible why they are attracted to those nodules! They are susceptible to electrolysed/pure-oxygen and it resembles their biology. Best reason to be curious.

@Thunderhammer: Yes, awnings! Maybe this is the reason why they use those "metal plants" you wanted. The plants do not produce the oxygen, but their leaves keep it on the desired level (for longer). The oxygen comes either from the paved ground or (later) from the scientific improved geobatteries which for example pipe the oxygen so that it will rise close to the stems of those plants, The oxygen is then trapped below those "umbrellas" for longer until "breathed away".

@Thunderhammer: Do they have abilities like electric eels so they can use this as "weapon" against harmful humans? Or just for electrolysis purposes?

@Antares Seeing how they live in saltwater and saltwater is highly conductive, I chose to limit it to that. At least until they find a way to weaponize it. For now, the closest they'll come to weaponize it is when something tries to damage their gills and get a nasty shock when they're too close. Considering adding toxins to the gills to save them from having to use electrolysis too much.

@Antares If you produce more oxygen at depth, in a region that is not already saturated, the extra oxygen will not rise to the surface--it will dissolve into the water and stay there, until you have produced enough to supersaturate the water. And saturation points increase with pressure, so the deep ocean is essentially never fully saturated, and you could produce quite a lot of additional oxygen before any of it starts to bubble out.
